# SSRS Web Front End

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Morning,

For some reason when I browse to http://servername/ssrs I now get a directory listing of the folders within my SSRS installation. This does include all of our reports.

Does anyone know why I'm not seeing the web front end anymore?

-- There's a possiblility that the virtual directory was changed (and then changed back again!) but I can't see how this would affect things?

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it.

The web service virtual directory and the report manager virtual directory were the same.

When the user borwsed to the URL they were presented with the web service "view".

Making them different fixes the issue!